# Running SSIS Execute Process Task using Powershell ISE

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting, powershell-ise

I am trying to run an SSIS package via PowerShell ISE

```
Executable: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowershell\v1.0\PowerShell.exe
Arguments:  N:\PowerShell\Move-Item.ps1
```

But the problem is the Arguments files is in the network drive which has no SSIS. My SSIS is in a Server called PFACESQAA. The Executable is from my network drive (Active Directory Domain). How do I run this from the Active Directory Domain or what is the best way to run this. I hope I made sense.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Powershell´s `-file` parameter works with network paths just fine, here is an example:

`powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -file \\server\share\file.ps1`

Comment: is this what I shoud put in the Executable in Execute Process Task in SSIS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowershell\v1.0\PowerShell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -file \\server\share\file.ps1

Comment: @Djbril i am not really familiar with SSIS but after having a quick look at it i would suggest the following: 
Executable: C:\Windows\System32\Powershell\v1.0\Powershell.exe
Arguments: -executionpolicy bypass -file \\server\share\file.ps1